# Escape HTML in Jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm writing my blog using jinja2. Many of my blog articles contain html snippets as code examples, but replacing < and > with &gt; and &lt; is tedious and annoying. I want to do something like this:

```
<pre><code class="html">
  {% escapehtml %}
  <div>This is how you make a div</div>
  {% endescapehtml %}
</pre></code>
```

I'd like the result to render the pre and code tags, but escape the div. I've tried using autoescape, verbatim, and raw, but none of them seem to do what I want (I believe they center around javascript and jinja's {{}} escaping). Is there a built in way to do this? Do I need to write my own template tag?

Answer (score 2):

[Filter sections](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#id11) allow you to apply regular Jinja2 filters on a block of template data.

Just wrap the code in the special *filter* section:

```
<pre><code class="html">
  {% filter escape %}
  <div>This is how you make a div</div>
  {% endfilter %}
</pre></code>
```